# How to access/iterate over all non-unique keys in an unordered_multimap?

Tags: c++, iterator, hashtable, unordered-map

I would like to access/iterate over all non-unique keys in an unordered_multimap.
The hash table basically is a map from a signature `<SIG>` that does indeed occur more than once in practice to identifiers `<ID>`. I would like to find those entries in the hash table where  occurs once.

Currently I use this approach:

```
// map <SIG> -> <ID>
typedef unordered_multimap<int, int>    HashTable;
HashTable& ht = ...;
for(HashTable::iterator it = ht.begin(); it != ht.end(); ++it)
{
    size_t n=0;
    std::pair<HashTable::iterator, HashTable::iterator> itpair = ht.equal_range(it->first); 
    for (   ; itpair.first != itpair.second; ++itpair.first) {  
        ++n;
    }
    if( n > 1 ){ // access those items again as the previous iterators are not valid anymore
        std::pair<HashTable::iterator, HashTable::iterator> itpair = ht.equal_range(it->first); 
        for (   ; itpair.first != itpair.second; ++itpair.first) {  
           // do something with those items
        }
    }
}
```

This is certainly not efficient as the outer loop iterates over all elements of the hash table (via `ht.begin()`) and the inner loop tests if the corresponding key is present more than once.

Is there a more efficient or elegant way to do this?

Note: I know that with a `unordered_map` instead of `unordered_multimap` I wouldn't have this issue but due to application requirements I must be able to store multiple keys `<SIG>` pointing to different identifiers `<ID>`. Also, an `unordered_map<SIG, vector<ID> >` is not a good choice for me as it uses roughly 150% of memory as I have many unique keys and `vector<ID>` adds quite a bit of overhead for each item.

Comment: You could keep a separate `map` up to date as you add to and remove from the `multi_map`.

Comment: Yes, but this would require double storage and this infeasible due to limited memory constraints.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [`std::unordered_multimap::count()`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/unordered_map/unordered_multimap/count/) to determine the number of elements with a specific key. This saves you the first inner loop.

You cannot prevent iterating over the whole `HashTable`. For that, the `HashTable` would have to maintain a second index that maps cardinality to keys. This would introduce significant runtime and storage overhead and is only usefull in a small number of cases.

You can hide the outer loop using [`std::for_each()`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/algorithm/for_each/), but I don't think it's worth it.

Answer (score 0):

I think that you should change your data model to something like:

```
std::map<int, std::vector<int> > ht;
```

Then you could easily iterate over map, and check how many items each element contains with `size()`

But in this situation building a data structure and reading it in linear mode is a little bit more complicated.

Comment: This is not better than using `unordered_map<SIG, vector<ID> >`. A node-based container like `set` is not necessary as I know that my inserted IDs will be unique.